# How do I utilize Webclient.DownloadFile or DownloadString if the website uses SSL?

Tags: c#, ssl, download, webclient

I'm writing a small utility that scrapes a webpage and emails me if the class I want has open seats. See the follow url:

[Math Classes](https://grim.westga.edu/pls/UWGP_DAD/hwwkbull.p_us_subj_list?term_code=201108&subj=math&levl=US)

However, I get an error everytime I execute the following code:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            //var html = client.DownloadString("https://grim.westga.edu/pls/UWGP_DAD/hwwkbull.p_us_subj_list?term_code=201108&subj=math&levl=US");
            client.DownloadFile(@"https://grim.westga.edu/pls/UWGP_DAD/hwwkbull.p_us_subj_list?term_code=201108&subj=math&levl=US", @"C:\file.txt");
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you posted also supports simple HTTP.

See here: http://grim.westga.edu/pls/UWGP_DAD/hwwkbull.p_us_subj_list?term_code=201108&subj=math&levl=US

Try removing your s from the url and see if that works.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that